# Changing my app name after uploading on the App Store?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I first created my app I've made a silly name.. i thought that the name of the app is the name I put on the App Store.

I was wrong. So when I change my **Product Name** in the Target>Build Settings>Packaging it changes my Bundle Identifier and make me unable to upload the new update for the app.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to change your app bundle name (never do it), you have to change the bundle display name field on your project info

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is change the value of "Bundle Name" in your Info.plist to change the name of the app under your home screen icon.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `Bundle display name` instead of `Product name`. This will change name of the app in the device. To change the name of app in the AppStore you should send an update